# c3js slow data load speed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm making an interactive animation using c3js. I show my readers how the values of bars change by using the `chart.load` function.

```
var chart = c3.generate({ 
    data: {
        x:'Candidate',
        columns:[
            ['candidate','Liberal','Labor','Greens','Independent','Nationals','Independent'],
            ['first', 12000, 11000, 6500, 3000, 3000, 1000] //36500
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        order: null,
        groups: [['first','second']]
    }
})

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns:[
            ['candidate','Liberal','Labor','Greens','Independent','Nationals','Independent'],
            ['first', 12000, 11000, 6500, 3000, 3000, 1000],
            ['second', 0, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    });
}, 400)
```

This issue is that I would like to slow the data load function right down, so people have time to process what they're seeing.

Can the load function be slowed?

Answer (score 0):

Answer's [here](http://c3js.org/samples/transition_duration.html)

You can set duration of transition in the main chart object.